# Nth Largest element from a table sql Query

Tags: sql-server

can any one explain hiow this query works..It's for getting the Nth largest elemet from a table.here it's 4 th largest

```
SELECT a.ID
  FROM tblitem a
 WHERE (4) = (select count(*)
                from tblItem  b
               where b.id < a.id)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it's the 4th largest not the 5th smallest?

Comment: yeh tht's tru sir.u r right.can u explain how that query works :)

Comment: I've tested your query. It definitely chooses the 5th smallest id.

Comment: Just to warn you. This query will perform horrendously badly on large tables. In addition to marc's point above I notice that you have made not a single upvote either.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it helps to rewrite the query a bit:

```
SELECT a.ID,
    (select count(*) from tblItem b where b.id < a.id) as cnt
FROM tblitem a
```

Example: if the id column starts with 1 and increments with 2, the result will look like:

```
id   cnt
1    0     No rows with a smaller id, subquery returns 0
3    1     One row with a smaller id, subquery returns 1
5    2     ...
7    3
9    4
11   5
```

On the fifth row, `cnt = 4`, and that row is chosen by your `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
(select count(*) from tblItem  b where b.id < a.id)
```

is a subquery that finds the number of items (`count(*)`) in the table where its value is less than the current one (`a.id`).

```
4 = (select count(*) from tblItem  b where b.id < a.id)
```

and we pick the one that has exactly 4 items less than the current value. This means `a.id` should be the **5th smallest**.

To select the 4th largest element, change that `<` into `>=`.