# SQL query for nth most recent update

Tags: mysql, revisions

I have a revision table and I need to be able the nth most recent update.  I have a query that gives me the most recent revision record of enitity, but I need one for the nth most recent revision record.

```
revisions
--+---------+--------+----------+-------
id|entity_id|contents|revisor_fk|revised
```

The query must take input 0 to n.  If the input is 0 it is the most recent, 1 is one revision back or second most recent, 2 is to revisions back or the 3rd most recent, etc.  And if the input is more revisions back then the entity has revisions it should return no rows.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `revised` is the timestamp

```
SELECT fields
FROM revisions
WHERE entity_id = :your_entity_id
ORDER BY revised DESC
LIMIT :which_revision, 1
```

Comment: +1 This is the most simplistic query I have seen for this problem.  Very tight!

Comment: `LIMIT` is supported by MySQL, Postgres and SQLite. For approaches for other DBMSs, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Limiting_result_rows

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this at [2937755](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937755/nth-largest-element-from-a-table-sql-query)

```
SELECT *
  FROM revisions a
 WHERE (4) = (select count(*)
                from revisions b
               where b.`revised` > a.`revised`)AND
`entity_id` = 1
```

But @[Matti Virkkunen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227267/matti-virkkunen)'s solution is much nicer.