# Select Nth closest date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct, max

My database contains trade dates and expiry dates. I want to get the Nth next expiry date for a given date. This query works fine:

```
SELECT MAX(Expiry)
FROM   (SELECT TOP(@N) Expiry
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Expiry
                FROM MTM
                WHERE TradeDate = @Date
                  and Code = @Code
                  and Class = 'blablablabla') as D
        ORDER BY Expiry) as T
```

But can I do it without using the triple nesting? Basically I need to use `MAX`, `TOP` and `DISTINCT`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you not just do the inner query, then take the Nth item (since they will be ordered)?

Comment: @Floris How do I take the Nth item?

Comment: See for example the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937755/nth-largest-element-from-a-table-sql-query

Comment: @Floris Sorry I'm not sure how to apply that to my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two inner can be combined into `SELECT DISTINCT TOP`:

```
SELECT MAX(Expiry)
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@N) Expiry
        FROM MTM
        WHERE TradeDate = @Date
          and Code = @Code
          and Class = 'blablablabla'
        ORDER BY Expiry) as T
```

However, there will be no performance gain (query plans will be identical).

Comment: But it looks much better so I'll take it!